# Android Q access non-SDK interfaces - Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mSelectorPosition:I (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-10.0

need one help any way we can use old API in Android Q.

I am facing this issue in https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView

All works fine till Android P

How can I enable access to non-SDK interfaces?

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

```
2019-09-27 18:36:25.024 13800-13800/com.app.readyb W/com.app.readyb: Accessing hidden field Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mSelectorPosition:I (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
2019-09-27 18:36:25.029 13800-13800/com.app.readyb W/com.app.readyb.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mSelectorPosition in class Landroid/widget/AbsListView; (declaration of 'android.widget.AbsListView' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at com.app.readyb.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.ReflectionUtils.getFieldValue(ReflectionUtils.java:15)
        at com.app.readyb.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.FloatingGroupExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(FloatingGroupExpandableListView.java:195)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4388)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1765)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1765)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1256)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1426)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:806)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.V
2019-09-27 18:36:25.030 13800-13800/com.app.readyb D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2019-09-27 18:36:25.046 13800-13800/com.app.readyb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.readyb, PID: 13800
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.app.readyb.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.FloatingGroupExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(FloatingGroupExpandableListView.java:195)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4388)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1765)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1765)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1256)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1426)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20304)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21168)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21439)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:806)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20313)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
2019-09-27 18:36:25.046 13800-13800/com.app.readyb E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: For now if we can use proguard rules and accessible on android 10 it will be great

Answer (score 1):

> How can I enable access to non-SDK interfaces?

That is not possible.

Fix the library to not attempt to use this hidden field. Since the library has not been updated in five years, it is unlikely that the original developer will fix the problem.

Or, find a replacement library and use it.

Or, create your own replacement UI.

Comment: Thanks for update so is there any alternative of AbsListview.

Comment: do i need to replace AbsListview?

Comment: @Mahesh: You cannot replace `AbsListView`. That is a framework class. You need to not try to access its private fields by reflection.

Comment: if possible can you give any hint or example where this is done or similar so I can fix it ASAP.
It creates big issue on my production app.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, but you are using a [library](https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView) not updated for Android 10 with Target sdk KitKat (API 19) so really really old. You need to replace this library with something more updated and based on a `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

On Android P onwards, this library does not work. You can simply use android `ExpandableListView` instead. That will be one to one replaceable.

You can try with the sample project in FloatingGroupExpandableListView repository and just use `ExpandableListView` in place of `com.diegocarloslima.fgelv.lib.FloatingGroupExpandableListView`. It should work.